# SqlException Incorrect syntax near '?'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting sql exception in my query:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '?'. Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'User'.]

What am I doing wrong? And what does this exception means?

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myConnection = @"Data Source=REDDEVIL;Initial..."

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnection);

    HttpPostedFile postedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

    if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".bmp" ||
        fileExtension.ToLower() == ".gif" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png")
    {
        Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        byte[] bytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

        string query2 = "INSERT INTO Manager (ID,Name,Address,Phone,Cell,Email,DOB,Commission,Comments,Photo,User ID,IsActive) VALUES (?ID,?Name,?Address,?Phone,?Cell,?Email,?DOB,?Commission,?Comments,?Photo,?User_ID,?IsActive)";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, conn);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ID", mgrID.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Name", Name.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Address", address.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Phone", phoneNo.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Cell", CellNo.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Email", email.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?DOB", dob.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Commission", commission.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Comments", comments.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Photo", bytes);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?User_ID", System.DBNull.Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?IsActive", System.DBNull.Value);
        conn.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        Response.Redirect("~/Views/Portal/Dashboard.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Sql Server as database?

Comment: I am using Sql Server

Comment: Use `@` instead of `?` How did you come up with `?` actually?

Comment: You're using the SqlProvider , don`t you need to use @ instead of '? ' ?

Comment: BTW - your `else` (at least in the code above) is redundant and can be removed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To specify that it is a parameter you should use `@` instead of `?` in your sql query. Then in your creation of the parameter, you do not need the `?` either

```
string query2 = "INSERT INTO Manager (ID,Name,Address,Phone,Cell,Email,DOB,Commission,Comments,Photo,User_ID,IsActive) VALUES (@ID,@Name,@Address,@Phone,@Cell,@Email,@DOB,@Commission,@Comments,@Photo,@User_ID,@IsActive)";

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, conn);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", mgrID.Text);
```

---

And as Tim noticed in the section you are specifying the fields you have `...USER ID,....` - I assume you are missing a `_` between the two. (of if it is indeed called `user` then see Tim's suggestion with the `[]`

Comment: But the other problem is - what is even mentioned in the error message - that he uses the keyword `User`, he has to put it in brackets: `[User]`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - True. corrected answer. BTW, I assume that it is a typo and that it is missing `_` and not that it is a field called `USER` - but could be

Answer (score 2):

defining column name has its own rule, you have define column name as

> ,User ID,

which is incorrect, it must be a single word, so you have to put it in brackets like

> ,[User ID],